# Spring Security hasRole() doesn't work with JWT

Tags: spring-security, jwt

I implemented JWT with Spring Security.

Spring Security `/login` url returns a JWT which contains a role but when I try to access a URL which requires a role, it returns `403`.

```
"timestamp": 1507840896561,
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Access is denied",
    "path": "/teacher/dashboard"
```

I defined a role for `/teacher/**` like this in `WebSecurityConfig` which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```java
http
  .authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
  .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
  .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
  .antMatchers("/teacher/**").hasRole("TEACHER")
  .anyRequest().authenticated()

  .and()
  .formLogin()
  .loginPage("/login")
  .permitAll()

  .and()
  .logout()
  .permitAll();

http
  .csrf().disable();

http
  .formLogin()
  .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
  
  .and()
  .addFilterBefore(new SimpleCorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
  
  .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
  .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()));
```

I tried to set the parameter for `hasRole()` as `ROLE_TEACHER` and Spring Security warned me not to use `ROLE_`prefix. I also tried `hasAuthority("TEACHER") and again got` 403`.

Payload of my JWT:

```json
{
  "sub": "org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@394ca6ef: Username: teacher@postman.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_TEACHER",
  "exp": 1508704641
}
```

Token has `Granted Authorities: ROLE_TEACHER` but I keep getting access denied error. Am I missing something or is there any other implementation for defining roles for urls?

Comment: Could you please add Spring Security logs with `DEBUG` level set (in your log configuration) to your question.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: @Hiru I changed the whole approach for this issue. I no longer use this approach.

Comment: @Eniss Thanks for reaching out. In my case I had not added roles in jwt claims. Now its working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Change your http config like that and try again,

```
.antMatchers("/teacher/**").access("hasAnyRole('TEACHER')")
```

hope this will work fine.

You can also check role in method level security using

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_TEACHER')")
```

To use `@PreAuthorize` you need to enabled it first. To do that extends your `MethodSecurityConfig` class with `GolbalMethodSecurityConfiguration` and add a annotation

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
```

`prePostEnabled = true` enables your application to authorize `before (pre)` and `after (post)` basis. Its your turn which one is suitable for you.

Comment: I first tried your 1st solution and got 403 again. Then I tried the 2nd one and I could access the URL whether or not I had token or any role. I still couldn't succeed.

Comment: Debug your code when request comes and see which role exist in your request. Something like `request.isUserInRole()`